# Cocos2d callback function

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-iphone

I am brand new to cocos2d programming and although I have programmed in C++ (17+ years ago) a lot has changed and I am struggling with the basics.

I have a function in gamescene which I want to pause the game, create a PauseScene instance and

```
void GameScene::pauseButtonCallback() {
    Director::getInstance()->pause();

    auto callbackResume = CallFunc::create([=](){
        GameScene::resumeGame();
    });

    auto pauseScene = PauseScene::createSceneWithCloseCallback(callbackResume);

    this->addChild(pauseScene, 5);
}
```

PauseScene.h

```
Scene* createSceneWithCloseCallback(CallFunc *callback);
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error on the line where I call PauseScene::createSceneWthCloseCallback(callbackResume) in the form of:

"call to non-static member function without an object argument?"

The idea here is I would set a callback block when instantiating the PauseScene which later gets invoked when the player hits the resume button.

Also I know that PauseScene is a child of GameScene and I can take a shortcut and just do parent->function() but I would like to accomplish this with callback blocks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use 'cococs2d-x' or 'cocos2dx' tag instead of 'cocos2d-iphone'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I was looking for by looking at the implementation of  MenuItemImage::create.

I used the ccMenuCallback which is defined as
    typedef std::function ccMenuCallback;

And in my PauseScene declaration

```
ccMenuCallback resumeCallback;

virtual bool init();

CREATE_FUNC(PauseScene);

static PauseScene* createSceneWithCloseCallback(const ccMenuCallback& callback);
```

The create method to set the callback:

```
PauseScene* PauseScene::createSceneWithCloseCallback(const ccMenuCallback& callback) {
   PauseScene  *ret = new (std::nothrow) PauseScene();

    if (ret && ret->init()) {
        ret->autorelease();
        ret->resumeCallback = callback;
        return ret;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
    return nullptr;
}
```

And then call the actual callback:

```
void PauseScene::resumeButtonCallback() {
    this->removeFromParent();

    this->resumeCallback(this);
}
```